# Getting all data in strapi database

Tags: flutter, graphql, strapi

I am using strapi database backend for my project and in my project in doctors there are 143 entry which they all are doctors. However, in GraphQL I just can't take it all at once. I can take them Doctors(start:0){} and Doctors(start:100){}. My question is how can I merge this to queries into one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pagination as mentioned [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/query-engine/order-pagination.html#pagination)

```
strapi.db.query('api::doctors').findMany({
  offset: 15, 
  limit: 10,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Doctors(pagination: {limit:-1 }){
........
}`;

To get all records you have to pass this in your graph query.
pagination: {limit:-1 }. That works for me